# Android Viewpager and orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-relativelayout

I have a custom (subclass) `RelativeLayout` which is being used in a `Fragment` and a `ViewPager`. I am using following code to set the height for one of the views in this layout, which is suppose to be half of the layout height:

```
override fun onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate()
    this.post {
        coverView = findViewById(R.id.cover)
        val layoutParams = coverView.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = this.height / 2
        coverView.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }
}
```

Everything seem ok until screen rotation. The view height is not being updated with new orientation. I have tried `onConfigurationChanged` to update the height, but doesn't seem to work either.

Should I use different approach to set the height? 
What else I can do to set to correct height when screen is rotated?

Comment: Please add the activity code and manifest file code.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to adjust my code to use `weightsum` with `LinearLayout`.

According to docs `onFinishInflate()` is called **after** the view and its children have been inflated.

If you want more custom handling, override `onMeasure()`.

Comment: I can't use linear layout, because the views are supposed to move around with user touch.

Comment: onMeasure() then? You can get the view parent dimensions(RelativeLayout?)  and use them for the children.

Comment: I should have a custom view (subclass) to be able to use OnMeasure. is that right?

Comment: Yes you need a subclass to override onMeasure. I don't know what you are trying to do exactly so I don't know if this would be the optimal choice. You can also check the onLayout method of the parent which handles the children's size and position.